# Cannot log into SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, login

I created a login name in SQL Server 2008 by

1. right click on security then new->login
2. specify a name , password and server map.
3. Right-click on SQL Server instance at root of Object Explorer, click on Properties
4. Select Security from the left pane.
5. Select the SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode radio button, and click OK.
6. Open up Services and restart the SQL Service (SQLEXPRESS) Windows service.

but it has following error:

> login failed for user gggggggg (microsoft sqlserver error 18456)

what is the problem?

Comment: a) did you give your "login" access to any of the databases in your server?? b) is this a "remote" SQL SErver Express (on another machine) - if so, is "remote login" enabled (it's OFF by default) ??

Comment: how can i enable 'remote login'?

Comment: See: http://www.datamasker.com/SSE2005_NetworkCfg.htm or thousands of other articles on that topic - Google is your friend !

Answer (score 0):

If the userId really exist, might be disabled on the server. Password might have expired and probably several other reasons ...